# How to realize a NFA?

Tags: javascript, nfa

How to write a function that recognizes words by this nondeterministic finite automaton? I don't understand how to apply a pseudo-code on picture to the scheme of a nondeterministic finite automaton. a word must be entered in the program. on the event start() is determined by recognized the word by this NFA or not.

```js
var states = {
    q0:{
        name: 'q0',
        isFinish: false,
        next: {
            'a': 'q3',
            'a': 'q6',
            'a': 'q5'
        }
    },

    q1: {
        name: 'q1',
        isFinish: false,
        next: {
            'a': 'q5',
            'a': 'q6'
        }
    },

    q3: {
      name: 'q3',
      isFinish: true,
      next: {
          'b':'q4'
      }
    },

    q4: {
        name: 'q4',
        isFinish: true,
        next: {
            'b': 'q4'
        }
    },

    q5: {
        name: 'q5',
        isFinish: false,
        next: {
            'b': 'q1'
        }
    }
};


var current = states.q0;

function input(symbol) {
    if(!current.next[symbol]) throw Error('invalid input');

    current = states[current.next[symbol]];
    console.log(current);
}

function start() {
    current = states.q0;
    input('a');
    input('b');
    input('a');

    if(current.isFinish){
        console.log('recognized');
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Start NFA" onclick="start()">
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: First, the obvious part: you can't have the same key in the same object more than once (i.e. the `next` object can only have one `a` key). I confess I did study this in college so I should know, but please remind me: the nondeterminism here would mean that when q0 gets the input "a", it executes all three branches, right?

Comment: The thing is, javascript doesn't have parallelism, which is what you'd need to implement an NFA. The closest you can get would be Promises. It's a pretty big topic so you'll have to do some reading up on it. What I,d recommend is to create copies of your state machine when it needs to branch, one copy per branch, execute them in separate Promises, and use `Promise.all()` to simulate them all finishing at once.

Comment: Several states marked with the same symbol can emerge from one state. added a pseudocode in the description of the question, which determines the admissibility of the word by the NFA.

Comment: What is "one cycle of work"? One "step" in the execution of the matching algorithm? If you mean "one input symbol", then you will have to do a breadth-first traversal over all the transitions of the nfa.

Comment: @MátéSafranka You don't need parallelism at all. Choosing multiple branches can simply be expressed through an appropriate data structure.

Comment: @elie_ You got the algorithm already - the current state of each step `i` is the set `R_i`. What exactly is your problem of putting that into JS code?

Comment: @Bergi, I don`t understand how to apply this algorithm to my code -_-

Comment: @elie_ Do you understand how the algorithm works at least?

Comment: @Bergi, I don't understand the algorithm well